# Non-triviality of "Weak closures of $*$-subalgebras are von Neumann algebras"

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

I suspect there is a slight error in Murphy's C*-algebras and Operator Theory:

Murphy defines a von Neumann algebra on a Hilbert space $H$ as a $*$-subalgebra of $B(H)$ that is strongly closed. I mention that because others define von Neumann algebras as those that are equal to their double commutants (if $id_H\in A$, the definitions are equivalent by the double commutant theorem, but if not, they are not the same; we can reduce to this definition by considering the unit of $A$ though, which is a projection and compressing to that subspace).

Anyway, after a number of results on von Neumann algebras and the strong and weak operator topologies, Murphy says "If $A$ is a $*$-subalgebra of $B(H)$, then its weak closure is a von Neumann algebra." and he refers to this as a simple observation BEFORE moving on to Kaplansky's density theorem. He also says that this will be used in the proof of Kaplansky's theorem (but I cannot spot where he uses it).

I don't think this is trivial without Kaplansky's help. I mean, obviously, since convex sets have equal strong and weak closures, if $A$ is a $*$-subalgebra of $B(H)$ then $\overline{A}^{WOT}=\overline{A}^{SOT}$, so this is indeed strongly closed. By weak continuity of involution, it is a self-adjoint set. It is obviously a linear subspace. But why is this a **subalgebra**?

**Using** Kaplansky's theorem, I can see why this is true: If $u,v\in\overline{A}^{SOT}$, then we can find a *norm-bounded* (by Kaplansky) net $(u_\lambda)\subset A$ with $u_\lambda\xrightarrow{SOT}u$ and let $(v_\lambda)\subset A$ be a net with $v_\lambda\xrightarrow{SOT}v$. Then since multiplication restricted on $S\times B(H)\to B(H)$ where $S$ is a bounded subset of $B(H)$ is strongly continuous, we get that $uv\in\overline{A}^{SOT}$ and we are done.

Is there something that obvious that I am missing out?

Comment: Why can you assume the net is norm-bounded? I don't see how this follows from Kaplansky's theorem.

Comment: @user745578 the element u divided by its norm lies in the ball of self adjoints so it may be approxinated by a self adjoint net in the ball. Scaling is sot continuous so after scaling by norm of u we get a bounded net converging to u

Comment: Ok, but the hypothesis of Kaplansky starts with a $C^*$-algebra $A$ with strong closure $B$. I guess here you apply Kaplansky with $A$ the given $*$-algebra and $B$the weak=strong closure. But $A$ itself is not a $C^*$-algebra so how does Kaplansky apply?

Comment: @user745578 You're right, but Kaplansky's theorem can be generalized for $*$-algebras, see for example Kadison's book. I've had wondered about this and I think I had checked that if $A$ is a $*$-algebra then the norm-closure of $\overline{A}^{SOT}$ is equal to the strong closure of $\overline{A}^{\|\cdot\|}$, so this helps us generalize to $*$-algebras

Comment: Hmmm, let me think some more about that! Thanks for the hint! Basically this is saying that "norm and strong closures" commute? Does this hold for arbitrary subsets or do we need convexity or something like that?

Comment: @user745578 Yes, this is what I'm saying. I do not recall though, I am not 100% sure that this is true but I remember using this in my understanding of the generalization to $*$-algebras. Wild guess: we need the $*$-alg structure but we can see if the proof requires it or not.

Comment: Alright thanks! I will see if I can prove something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112900/discussion-between-justdroppedin-and-user745578).

Comment: @user745578 I have moved this to chat so we can discuss it more

Comment: Upon revisting this question, I am slightly confused. Can't you just say $u_\lambda v=$s-$\lim_\mu u_\lambda v_\mu\in \bar A^{SOT}$ and then $uv=$s-$\lim_\lambda u_\lambda v\in \bar A^{SOT}$ by separate continuity of multiplication in SOT? Or am I missing something? @MartinArgerami

Comment: @MaoWao I think you're right, I don't see why not. Since then I've used this type of argument you're mentioning many times, I like to think I would be able to think of this very simple answer myself today. I was confused by very simple things 2 years ago:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right. But you already know that in the non-degenerate case the wot/sot closure agrees with the double commutant, which is an algebra.

Even if $A$ is degenerate, unital or not, you can do the following.

- Let
  $$
  p=\inf\{q\in A'':\ q\ \text{ is a projection such that }qa=a\ \text{ for all }a\in A\}.
  $$
  This infimum exists: the definition above is equivalent to $p$ being the projection onto the subspace $\bigcap_q qH$.
- $p\in A''$. Indeed, if $T\in A'$ is selfadjoint, then $TqH=qTH\subset qH$, and so $TpH\subset pH$. This implies that $pTp=Tp$; taking adjoints, $Tp=pT$. If $T\in A'$ it is a linear combination of selfadjoints, so $p\in A''$.
- You have $pA=A$, and $(1-p)A=0$, $p\in A''$. Let $A_1=A+\mathbb C\,(1-p)$. It is easy to check that $A_1'=pA'+(1-p)B(H)(1-p)$, and similarly that $A_1''=pA''+ \mathbb C(1-p)$.
- You can also check that $\overline{A_1}^{SOT}=\overline{A}^{SOT}+\mathbb C(1-p)$, and that $p\overline{A}^{SOT}=\overline{pA}^{SOT}=\overline{A}^{SOT}_{\vphantom{SOT}}$.
- It follows that
  $$
  \overline{A}^{SOT}=p\overline{A_1}^{SOT}=pA'',
  $$
  which is an algebra (note that $p\in A'\cap A''$).

The above is most often not necessary, because one considers von Neumann algebras  represented non-degenerately (that is, "multiplied by $p$"), and that's probably while it is often glossed over (I'm not even sure if I have seen it explicitly in any textbook).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I'm a bit confused:
1) How do you mean " you already know that the wot/sot closure agrees with the double commutant"? I know this if $id_H\in A$, but not in general
2) I do not understand the second paragraph: first of all, why does $\overline{A}^{SOT}$ have a unit? The proof that von Neumann algebras are unital uses approximate units (something we cannot do here, since we do not have a priori algebraic structure). Also, how do you mean "show that the double commutant has the same form" ?

Comment: The norm closure of $A$ is included in the SOT closure, so you do have approximate units. That said, they are not needed here. I have added more detail to the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, you have been of great help (again). Sorry that I could not fill in the details myself, I am just now entering the field of Operator Algebras.

Comment: No need to apologize at all. And if you are a beginner, your question was very insightful.

Comment: @MartinArgerami The SOT-closure of a $*$-algebra $A$ is definitely not equal $A''$. Indeed, consider any degenerate $*$-algebra $A$. Then $1$ is not in the strong closure but $1 \in A''$. I.e. the inclusion $\overline{A}^{\operatorname{SOT}}\subseteq A''$ can be strict. If the algebra is non-degenerate, this problem doesn't occur. The same story applies for the WOT-closure because the WOT-closure = SOT-closure of any $*$-algebra.

Comment: @QuantumSpace: I don't follow? Where did I say so? The whole point of the answer is to deal with that issue.

Comment: @MartinArgerami In your first sentence? Or are you assuming your algebra to be unital there?

Comment: Yes, I am (I was? This was written almost two years ago). That's why the next sentence begins "if $A$ is not unital...". But I'll clarify that I'm talking about the non-degenerate case in the first paragraph.

Comment: @MartinArgerami My bad then. Apologies.

Comment: No need. That first sentence was not clear.